# Positioning page number on the right in specific place

Tags: fancyhdr, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to position the page number on the right footer but also have the possibility to move the number horizontally as I have a template underneath.

I've tried both `fancyhdr` and `scrlayer-scrpage` and none of them are working.

Using `fancyhdr` (it works but I can't customize it horizontally):

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\thepage}
```

Using `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
```

or

```
\rofoot*{\hspace{certain_value em}\pagemark}
```

The solution using

```
\fancyfootoffset{1cm}
```

is what I am looking for but I want to set all of this before the \begin{document} as I am adding it on a package.

[image]

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE) of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Done! I put some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fancyhdr` you can adjust the horizontal footer offset with the `\fancyfootoffset` command. Postive values shift right, negative values shift left.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=70mm,paperwidth=100mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\thepage}}}
\begin{document}
abc
\newpage
\fancyfootoffset{1cm}
def
\newpage
\fancyfootoffset{-1cm}
xyz
\end{document}
```

Result (note that the `geometry` package is used to make the pages smaller, this is only for the screenshot and can be removed):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, there's a way to do what \fancyfootoffset{1cm} does but before the \begin{document} because I want to add it on a package?

Comment: As far as I know the command works also when you put it in the preamble (i.e., before `\begin{document}`).